# Adding missing class to an External JAR

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am trying to run a sample project. Initially it gave me errors saying missing jar file `android-support-v4.jar`. So I added external JAR file and then compiled but now there is a class missing in one of that JAR packages which is being referred.

On searching I also found that class on github but now the problem is how do I add it. If I right-click project -> new -> class, it gives me options to add class for all other JARs except this external JAR. Really stuck.

Comment: check the version of your jar, is the code on github and jar you deployed are of same version

Comment: which class is missing?

Comment: Some information [on adding requests for urgency to your questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), please read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding that class in Your project and then import it in Your Activity class where You need that class. Otherwise you have to check proper version of jar you need(You can find it on Github, where you found class) and then put this jar in lib folder of your Project. Let me know if it works.

Comment: yes i added this class to my local package and changed reference in the code and it works. Cheers :)